# how to include bootstrap.bundle.min.js script in azure ad b2c

Tags: javascript, html, azure, azure-ad-b2c

I have added the script of bootstrap.bundle.min.js for the carousel but the indicators are not automatically working moving from one to another indicator. version of bootstrap I am using is V5.
I have provided the cshtml file to loadURI in custom policy.

I have added the script of bootstrap.bundle.min.js for the carousel but the indicators are not automatically working moving from one to another indicator. version of bootstrap I am using is V5.
I have provided the cshtml file to loadURI in custom policy.

I am expecting for carousel to work automatically to move slide at certain intervals.

Comment: Hi. Did you get this to work in Azure B2C? I have the same issue. The carousel works, but the slides don't move automatically

Answer (score 0):

You have to 'enable' Javascript in the custom policy.

```
<RelyingParty>
  <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="SignUpOrSignIn" />
  <UserJourneyBehaviors>
    <ScriptExecution>Allow</ScriptExecution>
  </UserJourneyBehaviors>
</RelyingParty>
```

Have you done that already? See here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/javascript-and-page-layout?pivots=b2c-custom-policy

Also, "make sure to use the absolute URL and not a relative URL". It is explained in the URL above under "Guidelines for using JavaScript".

Comment: By what he is saying, the carousel works (meaning the script is enabled). What's not working is the automatic sliding of the carousel. I have the same issue. If you click on the indicators, it works fine. But initially, it does not move automatically.